# Вывод строки посимвольно на fortran

Tags: массивы, символы, fortran

Всем хорошего дня. Собственно вопрос в том, как обратиться к конкретному символу в строке типа char на языку fortran?

```
x="hahvlcundagvd"
print *,x(1:1)
```

Этот вариант работает, но увы мне не подходит так как парсер сторонней библиотеки не воспринимает срезы (библиотеку сменить не возможно так как другой такой нет). Задача как раз в том, чтобы избавиться от срезов (обратиться к определенному символу в строке и проверить равен ли он необходимому значению).